# Blank screen after resume from suspend on 14.04 (installed on Samsung NP900X3A)

Tags: 14.04, suspend, samsung

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my ultrabook Samsung NP900X3A. The main problem I get is the strange behaviour of the computer after resume from suspend: it seems to recover, but nothing appears on the screen, and the only way out is to press the power button to turn off the computer.
Ubuntu 13.10 worked fine. Below I report the main characteristics of the computer:

Processor: Intel Core i5-2537M CPU @ 1.40GHz x 4
Graphics: Intel Sandybridge Mobile Intel® HD Graphics 3000